# View code running in screen?

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

I accidentally rm'd a python script. It is currently running in a detached screen session. Is there any way to recover the code from the screen session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The Python runtime does not hold the source code in memory while the script is running (instead, it holds the compiled representation).

Answer (score 0):

Just copy the last version from the backup or checkout it from the version control system. You use at least one of those, right?

Comment: Tried using git a few weeks ago, got frustrated, decided to get back to it later. First thing I did when I realized my mistake was apt-get git.